# How to show saved values in a CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am having a `HomeViewController` as a rootViewController.In that i have placed a `addButton` in a `barButtonItem`.If i click that `addButton` it shows NewConnectionViewController`.

HomeViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)onClickAddConnection:(id)sender 
{    
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NewConnectionViewController * nvc = (NewConnectionViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newConnectionIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
}
```

In `NewConnectionViewController` i have a placed a `connectionNoText`.If `connectionNoText` is equal to 435.It should show the values of Connection Details(Values am getting in a object called `connect`) in `HomeViewController`. i have to show the connection Detail values  using ChartView in `HomeViewController`.i am having a separate `UIView` class called `chartView`.

NewConnectionViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)Save:(id)sender
{
if ([stateText.text isEqualToString:@"Tamilnadu"])
{
    if ([connectionNoText.text isEqualToString:@"435"])
    {
        NSLog(@"ConnectionNo correct==>>%@",connect);
        HomeViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewidentifier"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];

    }
}
}
```

While Clicking Save Button i can able to call the `chartView`.But If i click `addButton` in homeViewController and i write 435 and i click save button means,It should show the ChartView with values Down to the firstView….Likewise it should add the chartView whenever we click save button…..If You Are Confused With this Paragraph means,Nothing Just  "Like Adding Values with ChartView to present it in HomeViewController,Also have to add One By one using tableView"

Comment: with 'rootViewController' do you mean the Window's rootViewController (aka the storyboard's initial view controller in this case) OR do you mean a navigationControllers rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

You need to make rootviecontroller as navigationcontroller to push a viewcontroller otherwise no referencing is present for self.navigationcontroller

Comment: Thats not a problem.I made `navigationController` as a `rootViewController`.my problem is How to show the `ChartView` one by one in `HomeViewController` using `coredata`.

Comment: chartView - is it related to graphs? If so do not use tableview,scrollview is better.